In Linux (POSIX), how to forward stdin to forked child process while inspect the content?
I'm developing a command line application to hijack the invocation of CLI tools like ls or cat. I need to inspect and analyze the original stdin content passed to them. However, I found it quite difficult to achive the followings:

The parent process can only read from stdin when the child tries to read from stdin.
The following code won't work:
int pipe[2];
// ...
char buf[1024];
int n;
while ((n = fread(stdin, buf, sizeof(buf)) != -1)
    write(pipe[1], buf, n);

as the parent don't exit when the child exits without reading from stdin.

When the parent read EOF from stdin, it forwards EOF to the child too.
So, how to write EOF to child's stdin?


Here's my last version code:
    auto pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
      std::cerr << "HIJACKER FORK FAILED\n";
      return -1;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
      close(childStdin[1]);
      dup2(childStdin[0], STDIN_FILENO);
      return execvp(gCmd.c_str(), newArgv.data());
    }

    close(childStdin[0]);
    while (true) {
      pollfd pfd{ childStdin[1], POLLOUT, 0 };
      if (poll(&pfd, 1, -1) == -1)
        break;
      if (gSigChild)
        break;

      char buf[4096];
      auto bytesRead = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf));
      if (bytesRead == -1) {
        close(childStdin[1]);
        fclose(stdinSave);
      } else {
        fwrite(buf, 1, bytesRead, stdinSave);
        write(childStdin[1], buf, bytesRead);
      }
    }
    fclose(stdinSave);

    int status;
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED) == -1) {
      std::cerr << "HIJACKER WAIT FAILED\n";
      return -1;
    }
    return WEXITSTATUS(status);

The problem of the code above is that it fails to achive requirement 1: The parent does read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf)) without confirming that whether the child is reading from stdin. if (poll(&pfd, 1, -1) == -1) can not confirm this point.
The fact is, I don't even know if there exits a sound way to check if the child process is reading from stdin. Some LLMs tell me to use pselect in the parent process to check this before doing reading. However, the child process may exit between fork() and pselect(), causing the parent to be blocked in pselect() forever.

You need to show the code where you create the process and the pipes. Also explain what exactly does not work. And don't bother mentioning LLMs in this context, they aren't any credible when it comes to programming question.

You could use LD_PRELOAD to replace the read() system call with a function you provide, and it can implement the interception that you want.

You never "write EOF to child's stdin".  You never "write EOF" at all.  You close the pipe.  When all the write sides of a pipe are closed and all of the data has been consumed from the pipe, a reader will get an EOF.  It's not something that is written; it is a sentinel that means all the write ends are closed.

Since you control the invocation of the "target" program, there are several options [some already mentioned by others]:

Create two pipes (via pipe) and attach one to the input and one to the output of the target program.
Create a pseudo TTY (see: man 7 pty) and run the program under that.
Create a shared library that intercepts read and write syscalls and use LD_PRELOAD to "force" it upon the target program.
Run the target program under ptrace. This is similar to what strace and gdb do. You can intercept any read or write syscalls. This is more involved than the shared library approach but, sometimes, can catch more things.

In the first two cases, your program will have to:

Read from the "real" input descriptor and send the data to the target program's input (pipe or pty).
Read from the target program's output (pipe or pty) and send the data to the "real" output descriptor.

For your purposes, the shared library approach (i.e. with LD_PRELOAD) may be the easiest to implement -- YMMV

For some examples, see my answers below ...
LD_PRELOAD examples:

Is it possible to change /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range for a single program?
How to Override A C System Call?

ptrace examples:

Ptrace options not working in parent process
ptrace not recording forked process despite setting PTRACE_SETOPTIONS to PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK

pty examples:

testing a c program that gets user input from the terminal
How to read serial with interrupt serial?

